# How do I have internal state for a custom logger which only takes &self?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a simple logger by implementing the [log crate](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.6/log/).

The logger should behave like this:

```
[1] First log message
[2] Second log message
[3] Third log message
```

To implement this, I have my logger struct

```
struct SeqLogger {
    seq: i64,
}
```

and implement the `Log` trait's

```
fn enabled(&self, metadata: &Metadata) -> bool
fn log(&self, record: &Record)
fn flush(&self)
```

In `log(&self, record: &Record)` implementation, I would do

```
fn log(&self, record: &Record) {
    println!("[{}] {}", self.seq, record.args());
    self.seq = self.seq + 1;
}
```

However, the compiler complains that `self` is not mutable. Am I working in a right way to implement this? How can I update the state of the logger without `&mut self`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the `logger` crate doesn't intend for loggers to have any internal state, so it forces them to be shared as immutable. This easies things a lot, in fact, since a logger should usually be shared between threads and used simultaneously, and that's not possible with `& mut self`.

However, there's a usual workaround: interior mutability. There's a type `std::cell::Cell` designed exactly for that use case: to have a immutable reference to something that should be mutable. Your internal state is simply an integer, so it's `Copy`, and we can just try to use `Cell` as-is:

```
extern crate log; // 0.4.5
use log::*;
use std::cell::Cell;

struct SeqLogger {
    seq: Cell<i64>,
}

impl Log for SeqLogger {

    fn log(&self, record: &Record) {
        println!("[{}] {}", self.seq.get(), record.args());
        self.seq.set(self.seq.get() + 1);
    }

    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &Metadata) -> bool { if false {true} else {unimplemented!()} }

    fn flush(&self) { unimplemented!(); }

}
```

However, the compiler immediately becomes angry again:

```
error[E0277]: `std::cell::Cell<i64>` cannot be shared between threads safely
 --> src/lib.rs:9:6
  |
9 | impl Log for SeqLogger {
  |      ^^^ `std::cell::Cell<i64>` cannot be shared between threads safely
  |
  = help: within `SeqLogger`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::cell::Cell<i64>`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `SeqLogger`
```

This makes sence, since, as I said before, the logger itself must be `Sync`, so we must guarantee that it's safe to share its contents too. At the same time, `Cell` is not `Sync` - exactly because of the interior mutability we're using here. Again, there's a usual way to fix it - `Mutex`:

```
extern crate log; // 0.4.5
use log::*;
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct SeqLogger {
    seq: Mutex<Cell<i64>>,
}

impl Log for SeqLogger {

    fn log(&self, record: &Record) {
        let seq = self.seq.lock().unwrap(); // perhaps replace this with match in production
        println!("[{}] {}", seq.get(), record.args());
        seq.set(seq.get() + 1);
    }

    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &Metadata) -> bool { if false {true} else {unimplemented!()} }

    fn flush(&self) { unimplemented!(); }

}
```

Now it compiles just fine.

[Playground with the last variant](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=8ad50635619bc1edce238f1daa9c0397)

---

EDIT: According to comments, we can strip one layer of indirection, since `Mutex` grants us both the internal mutability (sort of) and the `Sync`ability. So we can remove the `Cell` and dreference the `MutexGuard` directly:

```
// --snip--
fn log(&self, record: &Record) {
    let mut seq = self.seq.lock().unwrap(); // perhaps replace this with match in production
    println!("[{}] {}", *seq, record.args());
    *seq = *seq + 1;
}
// --snip--
```

And furthermore, since our state is just an integer, we can use [a standard atomic type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicIsize.html) instead of `Mutex`. Note that `AtomicI64` is unstable, so you might want to use `AtomicIsize` or `AtomicUsize` instead:

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicIsize, Ordering};

struct SeqLogger {
    seq: AtomicIsize,
}

impl Log for SeqLogger {

    fn log(&self, record: &Record) {
        let id = self.seq.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        println!("[{}] {}", id, record.args());
    }
    // --snip--
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=be7f02399047b0b885ec6518bf384c9f)

Comment: I think that give an exemple with flush that do nothing and enabled who just return `true` is better that show some strange if else condition with `unimplement!()`

Comment: Perhaps you're right, I just wanted to explicitly mark the places we're not using for now. It's just a question of habit, I think.

Comment: Thanks! And I am impressed by the threads safe compilation error :D

Comment: `Mutex<Cell<i64>>` ← There's no need to wrap a Cell inside the Mutex, `Mutex<i64>` is sufficient. You update the counter using `*seq += 1`.

Comment: Your addition will result in multiple logs having the same sequence if there is any concurrency (A reads 1, B reads 1, A set to 1+1, B set to 1+1); use [`fetch_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicIsize.html#method.fetch_add) instead.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Didn't work with atomics myself before, unhappily.

Comment: One more mistake found, and it'll be fair of me to make this post community wiki, it seems :) Thanks, fixed.